# How to copy songs from iPhone to Mac?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have audio data in iPhone but it looks iTunes does not allow me to directly copy data to a folder in my laptop, although I copied the data to iPhone using iTunes.

There are tools like iExplorer but why do I need such tool to copy my data back? Does Apple intentionally block us from moving our own data back from iTunes to laptop? If so, why?

[image: iTunes showing On My Device playlist containing songs]

iTunes file sharing does not work because music player is not in the list.

[image: File Sharing missing Music app]

Comment: iExplorer will work when everything else fails, or is not possible through native iOS mechanisms. It's been in my toolbox for years.

Comment: At the end of the day, any design decision is "intentional". In which app do you play  the Spanish course on your phone? How did they get into that app in the first place?

Comment: You have also AnyTrans with a free trial period, the remove it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about why Apple does things the way it does are off-topic in general.